# How to use jquery drag+drop on to a li tag

Tags: css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the following HTML items. The li tags are within a bootstrap tab structure. I think this is size related as my dragable class is 200px wide and the li tags are 100px wide.

```
   <li id="dropmessages1"><a href="#id" data-toggle="tab">Cat 1 </a></li>
   <li id="dropmessages2"><a href="#id" data-toggle="tab">Cat 2 </a></li>

   <div id="1" class="dragable"><a href="" class="list-group-item"></a></div>
   <div id="2" class="dragable"><a href="" class="list-group-item"></a></div>
```

and the following jquery code.

```
   $( init );

   function init() {
   $('.dragable').draggable({
   cursor: 'move',
   revert: true
   });

   $('#dropmessages1').droppable({
   drop: handleDropEvent
   } );

   $('#dropmessages2').droppable({
   drop: handleDropEvent
   } );
   }


  function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {

  var draggable = ui.draggable;
  alert( 'The message  with ID "' + draggable.attr('id') + '" was dropped onto me!' );
  }
```

I am able to drag the "dragable" items, but I cannot drop them on the LI items. Is it possible to drop items on to an li tag?

Comment: Your code is working fine. Check: https://jsfiddle.net/0psyq0ud/

Comment: please visit this links Drag : https://jqueryui.com/draggable/     Drop: https://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Answer (score 0):

hi check the below code:

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1 {width:350px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `revert` option from `draggable`

```
$('.dragable').draggable({
   cursor: 'move'
   //revert: true //No need of this
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/0psyq0ud/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Remove your revert option in draggable

```
$('.dragable').draggable({
   cursor: 'move',
  // revert: true
   });
```

> If you use revert , object comes back to same place from where it was
>   dragged.

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
    $('#dropmessages1').droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: handleDropEvent
    } );
```

This allows to drag a large area onto a smaller one.